# Transaction dropped and replaced in etherscan

Tags: etherscan

I have transfered my ETH to my friend and the transaction status shows as "Dropped & Replaced" in etherscan, but it's still pending:

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x9d60ea69e3796607cc52e50a680051fb5d54abd5657d441d0bccdfe8a3935180

So basically my wallet is stuck. Is there something I can do about it?

Comment: Your transaction has been replaced by this one https://etherscan.io/tx/0x1a79cd50f7e8f2192866ad4c7ebc399ed9a00862958272937254b0403b98c5c0 which has succeeded.

Comment: According to Etherscan your wallet doesn't have currently any pending transaction.